# how to retrieve all data and show in different cards

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show all rows in a database on different cards. php code will show only one row. I want to show all row have the right condition in cards.

```
<? $title= 'Web Develop'; 

 $quariy = $mysqli->query("select * from information where selector ='2'");
  $data = mysqli_fetch_array($quariy);

?>
<main class="py-4 container">
     <div class ="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <h4 class="card-header">
                    <a href="show.php" class="btn btn-primary">Go 
                    somewhere</a>
                </h4>
                    <div class="card-body"><?php echo $data['name']? 
                    ></div>
                   <div class="card-footer"><?php echo 
                    $data['more_information']?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Please don't delete your question immediately after receiving an answer

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resultset that contains more than one row must be processed in a loop, as the fetch functions return ONE row at time

```
<?php
$title= 'Web Develop'; 

$quariy = $mysqli->query("select * from information where selector ='2'");
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($quariy) ) :

?>
    <main class="py-4 container">
         <div class ="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <h4 class="card-header">
                        <a href="show.php" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="card-body"><?php echo $row['name']?></div>
                    <div class="card-footer"><?php echo $row['more_information']?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </main>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

> You may need to fit this to your layout requirements, but this covers the question of how to process a multiple row resultset.